# how to display value of text box number using renderUI shiny app R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I want to display the value of the textbox number be displayed when typing

and that what I am trying to do

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    h1("Enter One Number"),
    numericInput("number","enter a number", "" , min = 1 , max = 100),
           uiOutput("uu")
        
    )

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$uu <- renderUI({"you are typing " input$number })
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the string. It is not possible to just concatenate them inside a `renderUI`. In order to combine the strings use `paste`, `sprintf` or any appropriate string function.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Enter One Number"),
  numericInput("number","enter a number", "" , min = 1 , max = 100),
  uiOutput("uu"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$uu <- renderUI({paste("you are typing", input$number) })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply combine a text and an object in R, but you can use `paste` for such situations.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  h1("Enter One Number"),
  numericInput("number","enter a number", "" , min = 1 , max = 100),
  uiOutput("uu")
  
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$uu <- renderUI({paste0("you are typing ", input$number) })
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```